# Importing file is stopping the ability to insert data into database

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode

In my application, a user can ask a question and then anyone can see that question and post a response. I have the the questions shown in a table view and then you can push to a detail view to see the specific question and post a response. From the detail view, you can enter another view to see all the other answers. To do this I have to create a segue that carries over the question id. To do that I have to import the file that allows you to view all responses. Well my problem is that whenever I import the file, you can no longer post a response to the question. When the file isn't imported, you can post a response. What could be causing this problem?
This is the tableview file:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]){
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self->tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    //int row = [myIndexPath row];

    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row];

    detailViewController.TitleDetailModal = [info objectForKey:@"title"];
    detailViewController.BodyDetailModal = [info objectForKey:@"body"];
    detailViewController.post_id = [info objectForKey:@"id"];
}

}
```

That carries over data to the detail view. In the detail view, you can answer the question.

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

//#import "M_ResponsesViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message{

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];



UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                message:@"Your response has been posted!"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                 message:@"Please fill out all information"
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];



if([message isEqual:@""]){
    [alert1 show];
} else{

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, _post_id]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@" , kBody , message]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@" , kDate , dateString]];


    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    [alert show];
    [_response resignFirstResponder];
    _response.text = nil;
}

}


-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{

[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self postMessage:_response.text];


}








-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Responses"]){
    M_ResponsesViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.question_id = _post_id;



}

}
```

The problem is that when I uncomment the "M_ResponsesViewController.h" import, the post message method is no longer working in that no data is being added to the data base. However, when I keep that commented out, it works.

Comment: With such a generally vague question, you're going to have to supply more details. Post some code or be significantly more specific about how you're doing things.

Comment: Ok ill edit the question